# Codeanywhere - Can't go to 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a Chromebook user and my text editor is Codeanywhere. I'm currently working on my first Node.js project, but I noticed that I couldn't open http://127.0.0.1:8080. When I open the link, it says "this site cannot be reached".
Is that a bug in Codeanywhere?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't started your server on port 8080.

Comment: I started, but I just can't go on the page.

Comment: Does it work with your internal ip address?

Answer (score 1):

Codeanywhere bills itself as being a Cloud based IDE. It doesn't run on your computer.

Presumably, you aren't running your Node.js JavaScript on your computer either.

The [introductory tutorial](http://docs.codeanywhere.com/quicktutorial.html) shows that the project has a public facing hostname of `somesubdomain.box.codeanywhere.com`.

You'll need to identify the hostname that you code is running on, and use that, not the loopback IP address that points to your own computer.